# javascript function removes html parts

Tags: javascript, jquery

"p" is removed as a result from the javascript, but I need them for structuring purpose. How can i keep the html tags in the hidden/second textblock after javascript is run on the text?

```js
function AddReadMore() {
  //This limit you can set after how much characters you want to show Read More.
  var carLmt = 50;
  // Text to show when text is collapsed
  var readMoreTxt = " ... Read More";
  // Text to show when text is expanded
  var readLessTxt = " Read Less";
  //Traverse all selectors with this class and manupulate HTML part to show Read More
  $(".addReadMore").each(function() {
    if ($(this).find(".firstSec").length)
      return;
    var allstr = $(this).text();
    if (allstr.length > carLmt) {
      var firstSet = allstr.substring(0, carLmt);
      var secdHalf = allstr.substring(carLmt, allstr.length);
      var strtoadd = firstSet + "<span class='SecSec'>" + secdHalf + "</span><span class='readMore'  title='Click to Show More'>" + readMoreTxt + "</span><span class='readLess' title='Click to Show Less'>" + readLessTxt + "</span>";
      $(this).html(strtoadd);
    }
  });
  //Read More and Read Less Click Event binding
  $(document).on("click", ".readMore,.readLess", function() {
    $(this).closest(".addReadMore").toggleClass("showlesscontent showmorecontent");
  });
}
$(function() {
  //Calling function after Page Load
  AddReadMore();
});
```

```css
.addReadMore.showlesscontent .SecSec,
.addReadMore.showlesscontent .readLess {
  display: none;
}

.addReadMore.showmorecontent .readMore {
  display: none;
}

.addReadMore .readMore,
.addReadMore .readLess {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-left: 2px;
  color: blue;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.addReadMoreWrapTxt.showmorecontent .SecSec,
.addReadMoreWrapTxt.showmorecontent .readLess {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="addReadMore showlesscontent">
  <p>Es ist ein lang erwiesener Fakt, dass ein Leser vom Text abgelenkt wird, wenn er sich ein Layout ansieht. Der Punkt, Lorem Ipsum zu nutzen, ist, dass es mehr oder weniger die normale Anordnung von Buchstaben darstellt und somit nach lesbarer Sprache
    aussieht.</p>
  <p>Viele Desktop Publisher und Webeditoren nutzen mittlerweile Lorem Ipsum als den Standardtext, auch die Suche im Internet nach "lorem ipsum" macht viele Webseiten sichtbar, wo diese noch immer vorkommen. Mittlerweile gibt es mehrere Versionen des Lorem
    Ipsum, einige zufällig, andere bewusst (beeinflusst von Witz und des eigenen Geschmacks)Es ist ein lang erwiesener Fakt, dass ein Leser vom Text abgelenkt wird, wenn er sich ein Layout ansieht.</p>
  <p>Der Punkt, Lorem Ipsum zu nutzen, ist, dass es mehr oder weniger die normale Anordnung von Buchstaben darstellt und somit nach lesbarer Sprache aussieht. Viele Desktop Publisher und Webeditoren nutzen mittlerweile Lorem Ipsum als den Standardtext, auch
    die</p>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Fiddle playground: https://jsfiddle.net/jhnr7z8L/
Thank you!

Comment: FYI, no need for a jsFiddle link. You can create your runnable example **right here, on-site** using Stack Snippets; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/). One advantage to that is that you don't run the risk of forgetting to include something important in your question. (You don't seem to have made that mistake, but many, many do... :-) )

Comment: Thanks i will check it out for the future!

Comment: You're setting the innerHTML of the element that contains all those p tags.  If you didn't mean to overwrite those, where are you going to put strtoadd?

Comment: I´ve copied this code and try to make it run with the html tags. Sorry if i can´t answer your question. Javascript is for me like chinese on steroids.

Comment: What if you have **two or more** paragraphs within the first 50 characters? Yep. Back to the whiteboard.

Comment: There woun´t be two or more paragraph in the first 50 characters (in my case).

Comment: @tay you cannot be ever 100% sure though ;)

Comment: I strip the text via php to p sections. So i´m in control over the text lengths of the p sections - plus/minus. So that would not be the problem...

Comment: Is it OK if the "Read Less" appears on a new line or should it be right next to the last bit of text?

Comment: It should be right next to the text, because words are cutted in two, it saves place and it looks better. If you change ``carLmt``, than you will see the splitting of words...

Comment: @tay, are you sure you are talking about "Read Less" in your last comment? It looks as though your argument is more about "Read More"...

Answer (score 2):

You could apply recursion so to support any nesting of DOM elements. You would need to apply the `SecSec` class to potentially many more elements, which occur after the "Read More" element, but are still part of the `.addReadMore` DOM tree.

Here is how your code could be amended to support that:

```js
function AddReadMore() {
    var carLmt = 50;
    var readMoreTxt = " ... Read more";
    var readLessTxt = " Read less";
    $(".addReadMore").each(function() {
        if ($(this).find(".firstSec").length) return;
        var left = carLmt;

        function recur(elem) {
            $(elem).contents().each(function () {
                var allstr = $(this).text();
                // If breaking point is somewhere deeper within this element, recurse
                if (this.nodeType === 1 && 0 <= left && left <= allstr.length) return recur(this);
                if (left < 0) { // "Read more" was already added. 
                    // Hide all following elements as we backtrack:
                    return this.nodeType === 1 ? $(this).addClass("SecSec") 
                                               : $(this).wrap($("<span>").addClass("SecSec"));
                }
                left -= allstr.length;
                if (left >= 0) return; // Not yet there. Continue with siblings
                // Found the text node that needs to be clipped:
                this.nodeValue = allstr.slice(0, left);
                // Add the remainder of the text in an additional span element, and the link to expand
                $(this).after(
                    $("<span>").addClass("SecSec").text(allstr.slice(left)),
                    $("<span>").addClass("readMore").attr("title", "Click to show more").text(readMoreTxt),
                );
            });
        }
        recur(this);
        // The "read less" link should be at the very end of this element
        $(this).append(
            $("<span>").addClass("readLess").attr("title", "Click to show less").text(readLessTxt)
        );
    });
    //Read More and Read Less Click Event binding
    $(document).on("click", ".readMore,.readLess", function() {
        $(this).closest(".addReadMore").toggleClass("showlesscontent showmorecontent");
    });
}
$(function() {
    //Calling function after Page Load
    AddReadMore();
    $("#html").text($(".addReadMore").html());
    $("button").click(function () {
        $("#html").toggle();
    });
});
```

```css
.addReadMore.showlesscontent .SecSec,
.addReadMore.showlesscontent .readLess {
    display: none;
}
.addReadMore.showmorecontent .readMore {
    display: none;
}
.addReadMore .readMore,
.addReadMore .readLess {
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-left: 2px;
    color: blue;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.addReadMoreWrapTxt.showmorecontent .SecSec,
.addReadMoreWrapTxt.showmorecontent .readLess {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>toggle HTML</button>
<pre id="html" style="display:none"></pre>
<div class="addReadMore showlesscontent">
<p>Es ist ein lang erwiesener Fakt, dass ein Leser vom Text abgelenkt wird, wenn er sich ein Layout ansieht. Der Punkt, Lorem Ipsum zu nutzen, ist, dass es mehr oder weniger die normale Anordnung von Buchstaben darstellt und somit nach lesbarer Sprache aussieht.</p>
<p>Viele Desktop Publisher und Webeditoren nutzen mittlerweile Lorem Ipsum als den Standardtext, auch die Suche im Internet nach "lorem ipsum" macht viele Webseiten sichtbar, wo diese noch immer vorkommen. Mittlerweile gibt es mehrere Versionen des Lorem Ipsum, einige zufällig, andere bewusst (beeinflusst von Witz und des eigenen Geschmacks)Es ist ein lang erwiesener Fakt, dass ein Leser vom Text abgelenkt wird, wenn er sich ein Layout ansieht.</p>
<p>Der Punkt, Lorem Ipsum zu nutzen, ist, dass es mehr oder weniger die normale Anordnung von Buchstaben darstellt und somit nach lesbarer Sprache aussieht. Viele Desktop Publisher und Webeditoren nutzen mittlerweile Lorem Ipsum als den Standardtext, auch die</p>
</div>
```

Like your own code does, also this version does not remove nodes, so any event handlers that would exist on them remain active.

Comment: "Read less" seems to be creeping to the next line (re: comment on question) - just a simple style change though...

Comment: @MarkSchultheis, I added a comment on that now as well. It would not be trivial, because the end of the relevant HTML could be `</p></div></b></p></i></p>`... and then what would be the desired result?

Comment: Yea, I agree,  it feels like a "wrap" or some such and an inline-block or whatever.  I have not fully worked through that in my brain either - thus I made no suggested modification either and just a comment.

Comment: Works well, but adds a hidden ``<p>`` tag at the end, which disturbs my layout (box with background color). So i prefer the solution of @jeto at the moment. Just because it fits better with my layout. Thanks a lot!

Comment: and if i have ``<br />`` somewhere in the text, it is added somewhere else in the output!

Comment: Sorry, but I cannot reproduce those behaviours. When I run this snippet, and inspect the produced HTML, there is no hidden `<p>` tag at the end (other than of course the `<p>` tags which are already there, but which you want to hide). Also, when I add `<br />` it stays where it is. Are you sure this is not caused by some other code?

Comment: Nice example, but in this responsive era, I'd simply center bottom a `read more` button and a gradient overlay over the second line of text. There's too many cases to fight against such solutions - not worth it. Not to talk about *flash-of-content* By using a parent overflow element you can even animate it's height to create a more pleasant UX... anyways. I'd go back to the whiteboard...

Comment: I´ve meant the hidden p-sections. If you check with browser html inspector you will see an extra line for these sections, which is added to the layout as ``<p></p>``. Maybe i´m wrong, but also ``<br />`` appears under ``<span class="readMore" title="Click to show more"> ...`` I´ve tested it on my site and in jsfiddle. It behaves the same!

Comment: @tay, I don't see any additional `<p></p>`, nor a `<br />` below that "readMore". I'll update my answer to show the generated HTML in a separate area. That way there is no doubt.

Comment: @trincot inspecting the source code on Chrome: https://jsfiddle.net/b9h2rgnv/ - yeah, seems a bit messy

Comment: @tay, I added an "toggle HTML" button to see the HTML that is actually there. I took the opportunity to make one optimisation. Let me know where you see an issue.

Comment: I´ve meant there is the ``<p></p>`` in closed mode, which disturbs my page design. Now after adding the toggle, it seems, that it doesn´t have an extra line in the design (tested with chrome inspector). I´m a bit confused.

Comment: I had made a change in that last edit, so the SecSec class is applied at the highest possible level. I misunderstood your previous comments, looking for *additional* `p` elements that were *hidden*. But now I understand you were talking about the *existing* `p` elements that were not hidden. ;-)  Any way, let me know if there is any issue with it.

Comment: Ok, it seems that the ``<br />`` problem is solved, too. Can you tell me what the advantages are compared to the code of @Jeto. I´ve understood, that html tags at the beginning are a problem with the other code and it counts inaccurately. Are there other advantages or maybe disadvantages of your code? Maybe speed or something else, which is considerable?

Comment: @tay My code can fail if the paragraphs can contain "complex" HTML and the character limit is not completely accurate. It being very simple/quick is its main advantage, but trincot's answer is strictly better. While I'm at it, you should take a look at https://github.com/FrDH/dotdotdot-js, might help.

Comment: Also, if you have references to some elements, or event handlers (like click-handlers) bound to some of them, you will lose those with Jeto's answer, because there the HTML is recreated upon expanding. For speed, it is hard to compare. The initial phase will be faster with Jeto's answer, but then the open/close actions will be faster with my solution.

Comment: Not to throw a wrench in the discussion * not specific to this answer either; but also consider that a `p` element will automatically close if it encounters a block level element prior to the close `p` => `</p>` tag https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements

Answer (score 0):

I would store the full HTML into a `data-` attribute and restore it on demand.

Demo:

```js
var textCollapser = {
  charLimit: 400,
  readMoreTxt: ' ... Read More',
  readLessTxt: ' Read Less',
  
  collapse: function ($element) {
    // Do nothing if the text doesn't exceed character limit
    if ($element.text().length <= this.charLimit) {
      return;
    }
    // Store the current HTML into a data- attribute if it wasn't already
    $element.data('fullHtml', $element.data('fullHtml') || $element.html());
    // Collapse on char limit and remove any HTML "remains"
    $element.html($element.html()
      .substring(0, this.charLimit)
      .replace(/<[a-z]*\s*$|[a-z]*\s*\/?>$/i, '')
    );
    // Add the read more action to the last paragraph
    var $lastParagraph = $element.find('p:last');
    $lastParagraph = $lastParagraph.length ? $lastParagraph : $element;
    $lastParagraph.append($('<a>').addClass('readMore').text(this.readMoreTxt));
  },

  expand: function ($element) {
    // Restore the full HTML
    $element.html($element.data('fullHtml'));
    // Add the read less action to the last paragraph
    var $lastParagraph = $element.find('p:last');
    $lastParagraph = $lastParagraph.length ? $lastParagraph : $element;
    $lastParagraph.append($('<a>').addClass('readLess').text(this.readLessTxt));
  }
};

$(function () {
  $('.addReadMore').each(function () {
    textCollapser.collapse($(this));
  });
  
  $('.addReadMore').on('click', '.readMore', function () {
    textCollapser.expand($(this).closest('.addReadMore'));
  });
  
  $('.addReadMore').on('click', '.readLess', function () {
    textCollapser.collapse($(this).closest('.addReadMore'));
  });
});
```

```css
.addReadMore .readMore,
.addReadMore .readLess {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-left: 2px;
  color: blue;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="addReadMore">
  <p>Es ist ein lang erwiesener Fakt, dass ein Leser vom Text abgelenkt wird, wenn er sich ein Layout ansieht. Der Punkt, Lorem Ipsum zu nutzen, ist, dass es mehr oder weniger die normale Anordnung von Buchstaben darstellt und somit nach lesbarer Sprache
    aussieht.</p>
  <p>Viele Desktop Publisher und Webeditoren nutzen mittlerweile Lorem Ipsum als den Standardtext, auch die Suche im Internet nach "lorem ipsum" macht viele Webseiten sichtbar, wo diese noch immer vorkommen. Mittlerweile gibt es mehrere Versionen des Lorem
    Ipsum, einige zufällig, andere bewusst (beeinflusst von Witz und des eigenen Geschmacks)Es ist ein lang erwiesener Fakt, dass ein Leser vom Text abgelenkt wird, wenn er sich ein Layout ansieht.</p>
  <p>Der Punkt, Lorem Ipsum zu nutzen, ist, dass es mehr oder weniger die normale Anordnung von Buchstaben darstellt und somit nach lesbarer Sprache aussieht. Viele Desktop Publisher und Webeditoren nutzen mittlerweile Lorem Ipsum als den Standardtext, auch
    die</p>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

As @trincot pointed out, note that by doing it this "simply", the character limit won't be 100% accurate since it will cut into HTML tags themselves. Take a look as @trincot's answer for one that is more strict with that.

Comment: If `charLimit: 400`, the rendering is not consistent, i.e. all text is rendered in one paragraph, while a new paragraph started within that part.

Comment: @trincot Right, I was aware of that but should have mentioned it (felt like it was clean as long as the char limit wasn't too high and the text didn't contain much HTML formatting). I changed my answer to take this into account.

Comment: Oh, but now you are miscounting characters, by clipping the HTML (not the text) to the charLimit. This means `<p>` counts for 3, but it should not.

Comment: @trincot Also right. This supposes the char length can be an approximate value.

Comment: Let's hope the HTML does not have `<p class="newspapertext roman" lang="en" dir="ltr">some <span style="color: red">text</span></p>` ;-)